# iOS spriteNode background image differences between ios 7 and ios 8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, sprite-kit, skspritenode

i'm facing this problem on iOS(objective-c, not swift). I load a background image from images.xcassets and it displays properly on iOS 8, but not on iOS 7. Have anyone faced this problem before ?

This is the code i'm using:

```
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"xxx"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:background];
```

There are also differences in layouts (i'm not using xibs), but the first step is to solve the background :).

Below are the screenshots from ios 7 % ios 8.
[image]
[image]

Here is a screenshots with images.xcassets:

[image]
Thanks,have a great day, Alex.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how the image is not properly displayed?

Comment: in images.xcassets i have the image for iphone @2x, 960x640, in ios8 everything seems to work fine, but in ios 7 the image is bigger

Comment: You need to post more code related to the setup of your SKScene. Screenshots would be most helpful.

Comment: check scene's scaleMode, I believe the default may have changed so try setting it explicitly

Comment: add a launch image for iPh5: size 640 x 1136 pixels and name 
Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have updated the screenshots, the launchImages are added correctly in images.xcassets

Comment: your images are not covering all the screen... or the background image it's like in screenshots (you had others before)? Anyway.. I'm talking about launch images not about background images

Comment: that issue was from the launchImages, my image it's like in the screenshots. Btw, also tested scene's scaleMode to SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit - same behaviour

Comment: 1) try scale mode to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill    2) try to label your images (1x, 2x, 4-2x.. ) to see if they are loaded correctly

Comment: i just updated the answer, thanks for your notice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that ios 7 doesn't recognize that your app is launching in landscape mode so the frame is initialized with the portrait dimensions. I solved this with the following method :

```
- (CGSize)screenSize {
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    if ((NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        return CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
    }
    return screenSize;
}
```

You can find out more by searching for 'orientation-dependency' in iOS 8. Hope this will be usefull for you too.